# Bag sets identification please Star Wars © 2007

Tags: star-wars

I just purchased a box of random Lego with some sealed bags I’m wondering what they are. The guy I purchased from was vague but said he thinks they’re Star Wars. Note bags 4,5,6,7,8 are there. Mostly black, some technic parts throughout and ©2007 on each bag. Thanks[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: The "©2007" on the bags, just refer to the bags

Comment: looks like 7672-1: Rogue Shadow

Answer (score 7):

Based on the parts

- [Left Shell 3X10](https://brickset.com/parts/6106304/left-shell-3x10)

  [image]
- [Parabola 6X6](https://brickset.com/parts/4211796/parabola-6x6)
- [Rocket Step 4X4X2](https://brickset.com/parts/4143243/rocket-step-4x4x2)

  [image]
- [Technic Stick](https://brickset.com/parts/4211859/technic-stick)

  [image]
- [2M Fric. Snap W/Cross Hole](https://brickset.com/parts/4211865/2m-fric-snap-w-cross-hole)

  [image]
- [Jet Engine](https://brickset.com/parts/4263610/jet-engine)

  [image]
- and the Technic [rubber projectile](https://brickset.com/parts/4299625/arrow-8m-w-soft-upper-p) [launcher](https://brickset.com/parts/4499435/release-housing-6x2x2-ass)

it should be (as Uli commented) [7672-1: Rogue Shadow](https://brickset.com/inventories/7672-1):

[image]

Comment: Champion Zovits! I would have never worked that out. Thank you so much. Looks as though I’ve scored a good set cheap 